# How to get the returned value in PHP query

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this query below where I want to fetch the `id` from the table in the database:

```
$getId = DB::Select("select group_id from sm_group where group_name = '.$search.'" );
var_dump("returned ", $getId);
```

but this only returns:

> string(9) "returned " array(0) {}
>   No properties

Where what I want is the `id` which is an integer. Is there anyway I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use this to get a single column:

```
$id = DB::table('sm_group')->where('group_name', $search)->value('group_id');
```

However, since your query isn't returning any rows, it seems a match wasn't found.